# convert query results to nested objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class to represent my DB relationship:

```
public class Faclility{public List<Room> {get;set;}}
```

and the following is the EE query:

```
dbContext.Facilities.join(db.Room,f=>f.fUnitID,r=>r.fUnitID,(f,r)=> new ???)
```

How can I stuff all the Room object into the list of Facility object?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `GroupJoin` rather than a `Join`.  This will result in your selector accepting a single facility and a collection of rooms, rather than one of each.

Comment: this is sort of unrelated to the original question. Why is it that I can't seem to include a reference object using Group Join?`code`dbContext.Facilities.GroupJoin(db.Room.Include(x=>x.Chairs,f=>f.fUnitID,r=>r.fUnitID,(f,result)=> new {})`code`. Chairs objects are always null

Comment: @user1784014 Without seeing exactly what you're doing and the exact behavior, I couldn't comment.